# Prevent async method from returning until all tasks are completed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm still trying to understand the async/await pattern, but I'm also trying to achieve the following behavior:

A method A calls method B which runs a number of processes. Some of those processes can be run on separate threads while other things are being processed so that their return values will be available closer to when they are needed. Method B needs to not return control to the caller until all of these processes are completed.

Here is the test code that I am working with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CallProc();
    Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task CallProc()
{
    var two = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(5000, "two"));
    var one = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(500, "one"));
    var three = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(1500, "three"));

    // some process happens here

    var oneMessage = await one; // waits until one finishes and then snags it's value
    Console.WriteLine("Got message {0}", oneMessage);

    // some more stuff happens here

    var twoMessage = await two; // waits until two is finished and then snags it's value
    Console.WriteLine(twoMessage);

    // TODO: need to make sure that everything is completed before returning control to caller
}

public static string SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(int delayTime, string message, bool delay = true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting \"{0}\"", message);
    if(delay) Thread.Sleep(delayTime);
    return string.Format("Finished \"{0}\"", message);
}
```

Right now, what is happening is that everything words as I expected except that the method is returning before everything is finished, so the output shows "Program finished" while "two" is still running.

How do I write this so that `CallProc()` can execute those tasks asynchronously but delay returning until everything has been completed. In other words, `CallProc()` needs to run some tasks asynchronously, but `CallProc()` itself needs to be called synchronously.

Comment: Have you tried using a Task collection and use the Task.WaitAll() method?

Comment: I did. It yielded the same results. Control was returned to main() before everything finished

Comment: Why don't you just `await three` as well at the end?

Comment: Is there a specific order to your tasks? i.e. do you need to wait for `one` before you can do `// more stuff`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it's for show, to illustrate that there is more things that will happen before the method returns. I just wanted to show that the task was being started.

Comment: @James sorta. It depends on the situation. For example, three my be dependent on the result of one, but two might be able to run on it's own which is why I put them out of order here. But the point is that in the end, all tasks must be done before it returns

Comment: I'm not going to suggest this as an answer, because I'm not confident, but don't you just want to have CallProc().Wait(); It's the same as James' answer really, but CallProc can still be called asynchronously.

Comment: @Hammerstein that was my intention with the use of `WhenAll`, the idea being `CallProc` could be awaited externally.

Comment: @Hammerstein that actually appears to have done it! My output immediately reads that one two and three started, the pauses between one and two finishing and outputs those messages, then finally says program finished. Thank you. this addresses the idea that CallProc does some async stuff internally but the method itself is called synchronously as I asked.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic that does *kind of* defeat the purpose of `CallProc` being asynchronous to start with though.

Comment: CallProc isn't intended to be asynchronous -- it is just a control method, but the methods being called from within it *are* asynchronous. `async` on `CallProc` is just there to enable the await keyword.

Comment: Again, the intent is to give some long running processes a head start using data that is immediately available.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic if that's the case then really you just want to make `CallProc` a `void` type and use `WaitAll`.

Answer (score 6):

The idea of an asynchronous method, which is what you've written is that it will return control (approximately) immediately and the task that it returns will be marked as completed when the operation that it conceptually represents finishes.

This means that your program should either be looking at the resulting task to see when it finishes, or that you don't want an asynchronous method in the first place, and you should re-write `CallProc` synchronously rather than asynchronously.

To make `CallProc` synchronous simply remove `async` (and adjust the return type accordingly), and wait on each task instead of using `await`.

If `CallProc` really should be asynchronous then the caller should be adding a continuation (or using `await`) to perform an action when the task is completed, rather than when the method returns.

Comment: So maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what I'm wanting tasks one two and three to start running immediately (essentially giving them a head start on processing) and then only await them as they're need (i.e. if you're still not finished by now, then I'll wait, otherwise gimme the result and carry on). CallProc is only marked async so that I can use the await keyword in this fashion

Comment: @Sinaesthetic `await` and `Wait` mean *completely* different things. `Wait` means, "Block the thread until the task completes."  `await` means, "Return control of execution back to the caller, and execute the rest of the code in this method when the task that is being awaited finishes."  If you want the method to be syncrhonous, you use `Wait`.  If you want the method to be asynchronous, you use `await`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of awaiting each task individually why not just await all of them using `WhenAll`

```
public static async Task CallProc()
{
    var two = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(5000, "two"));
    var one = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(500, "one"));
    var three = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeSynchronousProcessIDontOwn(1500, "three"));

    // run synchronous tasks

    await Task.WhenAll(one, two, three);
}
```

If you would prefer to have `CallProc` block (i.e. not return until all tasks have finished) then remove the `async` declaration and use `Task.WaitAll` instead.

```
public static void CallProc()
{
    // start tasks

    Task.WaitAll(one, two, three);
}
```

Comment: @Servy yeah, but instead of waiting for tasks *individually*, why not just wait for them all to complete?

Comment: Because he's doing things after each `await` besides just awaiting the next task, or so the comments in the code state.

Comment: @Servy the OP didn't mention that those tasks need to be run in any particular order (I have asked for clarity).

Comment: They *aren't* run in a particular order.  They're performed in parallel, but the results of each task are performed in order, and don't necessarily need to wait until the other tasks are done.  Regardless, that's not really the point here.  Even if using `WhenAll` was more convenient, it doesn't solve the fact that *his program doesn't function as he expects, and you're suggesting a purely aesthetic change that won't affect the underlying behavior he is concerned about*.  So this absolutely fails to answer the question, regardless of whether or not this is a valid refactor in context.

Comment: This would in no way prevent the application from finishing, and the use of `WaitAll` alone would not be correct.  It's important that the code be either entirely synchronous or entirely asynchronous.  Mixing the two as you propose would be *very* bad.

Comment: @Servy I removed that part (got confused with `WhenAll` / `WaitAll`) and I am not proposing a *"mix"* nor suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to simply call `Wait()` on the result of `CallProc`. This will essentially wait for the task returned by `CallProc` to finish before it continues. Calling `Wait` in a GUI app can cause a deadlock but for a console app it is fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CallProc().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That will ensure that "Program finished" is printed after task two is finished.